# how to make data frame's list rows to string?

Tags: pandas, list, token

I have a dataframe each row is a list like this:

```
   word_count   id  token
    0       6   0   [customer, executive]
    1       6   0   [purchase]
    2       6   0   [purchase, agent]
    3       6   0   [housekeeping]
    4       6   0   [night, auditor, &, guest, reception, agent]
```

I wanna convert the list to string like this:

```
  word_count id token
0       6   0   customer executive
1       6   0   purchase
2       6   0   purchase agent
3       6   0   housekeeping
4       6   0   night auditor & guest reception agent
```

I did the following method but when I see de.head() nothing change:

```
for index, row in de.iterrows():
    row['token']=' '.join(str(e) for e in row['token'])
de.head()
```

and

```
for index, row in de.iterrows():
    row['token']=' '.join(row['token'])
de.head()
```

and

```
for index, row in de.iterrows():
    row['token']=' '.join(row['token']).replace(',' ,' ')
de.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension:

```
df['token'] = [' '.join(x) for x in df['token']]
```

Or `apply`:

```
df['token'] = df['token'].apply(' '.join)
```